# Does my uncircumcised friend still needs to be circumcised in order to join the meal for Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, commentaries, passover-seder-hagada, bo

The Korban Pesach was made to be able to keep a meal in order to hold a celebration which serves as a remembrance (Shemot 12:14, 16).

A remembrance of the moment we took a lamb and used it's blood to make a sign upon the the posts of the houses in which it was eaten, so that HaShem could skip those houses and they would not suffer the same destruction that was caused in the other houses, which would lead to the eventual Exodus.

These days we can't bring the Pesach sacrifice, because there is no Temple, but we still hold a meal in order to hold a celebration as a remembrance. So that part still stands.

But does this mean that the command (Shemot 12:44, 48, Bamidbar 9:14) of circumcision (which would allow one to join the meal of the Korban with the matzot and maror) now without the Korban becomes invalid? (So one could join in a uncircumcised state).

The fact is that one still joins a meal which is kept to hold a celebration as a remembrance, and serves the exact same purpose, wouldn't it therefore be more appropriate to keep this command although the meal doesn't involve a Pesach sacrifice.

Comment: Meal of pesach is not korban pesach

Comment: @Rish I think OP refers to an uncircumcised Jew, not a Gentile. So, it' snot a dupe of that question. Thus, I believe kouty's comment applies.

Comment: @Rish my question is not about wether a Ger or Jew is allowed to join if uncircumcised, but about wether they are are or not allowed so because the absence of the Korban Pesach while it could be the command still applies because of the other facets.

Comment: @DanF see my comment regards Rish; I would like to know if it's allowed or not today because the Korban Pesach is missing, while it seems that although it is missing there are still a lot of similarities with the meal these days.

Comment: @Levi Just to clarify, you’re asking if an uncircumcised Jew is allowed to partake in a modern-day, post-second-Temple Pesach Seder in light of the prohibition upon him against eating from the Karban Pesach which no longer exists? I’m not following your line of logic. Even when the Mikdash stood and there was a Karban Pesach, an uncircumcised Jew could join the Seder - he just couldn’t eat the Karban (from what I understand - someone please correct me if I’m wrong, in which case there may be more basis to this question than I’d think).

Comment: @DonielF Yes correct, but would you say in ancient days one could keep a meal without bringing a Pesach offer and eating from it? Because the whole point seems to be one needed to do this in order to have this meal so that one could keep a celebration as a remembrance... and thus be circumcised in order to join in this event and be able to do the same as all the others who celebrate it.

Comment: @Levi I didn’t say a *circumcised* Jew could do it, but an *uncircumcised* Jew doesn’t have much of a choice.

Comment: @DonielF "to keep" means to slaughter the pesach, i.e. the zebach chag Pesach, the Korban Pesach in order to eat it at it's set time; of which it is said to to be a yom lezikaron v'chagotem a Chag l'HaShem... right? So for me it's if HaShem said: "Let's celebrate this day, so we remember it, in order to celebrate it you should take a lamb and keep it unto the fourteenth day and slaughter it at dusk, then you shall eat it, and so you shall do.. and so you shall eat.. and when your children ask about it you shall say.. etc..." To me it seems all to be inextricably/inseparably linked

Comment: @DonielF to celebrate means to have a meal. To have a meal means eating the Korban with other ingredients at the side. And to eat the Korban means to prepare it in proper manner...

Comment: @Levi Why is an uncircumcised person not allowed to attend the meal and be restricted in what he eats?

Comment: @DonielF good point, but where does it say so? Looking at the original commandments in the Tenach containing the word Pesach they all talk about the Korban or things related to it. And at that time it is clearly stated no uncircumcised person could eat thereof, which looks like one could not partake under those circumstances. Translating this to our time, the meal reminds us to the meal we should have, we keep as much of the original commandments intact as good as we can; by eating maror and matzot with it for example, so why shouldn't one stick to the commandment of circumcision also?

Comment: @Levi Those are exactly the verses I’m talking about. An uncircumcised person may not eat or the Pesach - but he is still obligated in Matzah and Marror nonetheless. Further, the Pesach Seder has nothing to do with the Karban beyond the fact that the Karban was eaten at the Seder. The only thing you *might, theoretically* be able to argue is that he can’t have the Afikoman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74844/discussion-between-donielf-and-levi).

Comment: @kouty the meal depended upon the Korban so although it's not the same in a ideal state the meal would consisting of a Korban with matzot and maror etc.. every command regards the word pesach hangs on or depends on this sacrifice that was to be slaughtered and eaten which formed the main element of a meal that was hold as a remembrance and celebration of the event that occured with the first time this sacrifice was brought.

Comment: @kouty so if the verse of 12 speaks of doing Pesach to me it means slaughter the zebach pesach, prepare it and it it during a meal.. but now we can't make such a sacrifice, but we still hold a meal and try to fulfill the commandments which still can be hold. So take the commandment to eat matzot and maror with the korban, without a Korban we now eat matzot and maror with the meal. Same could be applied to the commandment of circumcision, if it was a neccessary for eating the Korban then it could be a nevcessary for eating the meal.

Answer (score 9):

Many laws applied to the Passover offering that do not apply to the Seder. For example, the Passover offering can only be eaten by people who are Tahor (a specific form of ritual purity). There is no requirement to be Tahor to attend a Seder nowadays.

Similarly, the Passover offering had to be eaten only by the invited members of a group. Nowadays, anyone may walk in and join a Seder on the spot. [For those of you who think the invitation in "Ha Lachma Anya" is just a ritual, we once had some teens knock on our door just after we recited Ha Lachma Anya. Their previous Seder plans hadn't worked out so they came to us. Obviously, we invited them to join.]

Additionally, the Passover offering can only be done in Jerusalem. The Seder can, and indeed is, celebrated around the world.

Likewise, it would seem there is no specific need for a Jew to be circumcised in order to join a Seder. One may clearly invite a non-circumcised Jew to attend a Seder.

However, there *is* a requirement for every Jewish adult male to ensure that he receives a circumcision if his parents did not perform one for him and he is medically able to. He should be appropriately circumcised as Jews have been for millenia. Circumcision is a Jew's personal covenant with God, and perhaps an even more critical part of being Jewish than the Seder itself.

Comment: Citations to sources would improve this answer post.

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara ([Pesachim 28b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=28b&format=pdf)) states that an uncircumcised Jew is obligated to eat matzah like any other Jew, and derives this from a verse:

> ור' שמעון טמא ושהיה בדרך רחוקה לא איצטריך קרא דלא גרע מערל ובן נכר דכתיב (שמות יב, מח) וכל ערל לא יאכל בו בו הוא אינו אוכל אבל אוכל הוא במצה ובמרור
>
> ...it is written: “And no uncircumcised man shall eat of it” (Exodus 12:48). The added emphasis in “of it” indicates that only it, the Paschal lamb, he does not eat; however, he must eat matza and bitter herbs.

(Tosafot, ibid., s.v. *kol arel*, questions why a verse is even necessary, since matzah, unlike the korban pesach, is not a sanctified object.)

Comment: So what do the words: "and will keep/do/make the Pesach.." and "to come near and keep it" refer to, do these refer to bringing the zebach Chag Pesach, the Korban Pesach?

Comment: @Levi not sure what words you're referring to

Comment: ועשה פסח (ליהוה)

Comment: @Levi yes, that pasuk is talking about korban pesach

Comment: @wfb; but 'it' could also refer to the whole meal

Comment: @user4762 No, no it doesn’t. Read the passage again - starting back in verse 43 and continuing to 50. It’s all one topic - now read verse 46 in particular. “Don’t break a bone of it” applies to the Karban Pesach *and only the Karban Pesach.*

Comment: @DonielF I agree, but I don't think youre getting my point; because it seems that all these commandments hang upon this special sacrifice, for example Exodus 12:8 which mentions the maror, that's only eaten with the meat of the Korban, and Bamidbar 9:11 and Devarim 16:2-3 teach that matzot should be eaten with the Korban. Constantly these commandment refer to what to do and don't in reference to the Korban. So the whole 'meal aspect' is based upon the Korban. That leaves the possibility that it could refer to the whole meal, because the whole meal was based upon eating the Korban.

Comment: @DonielF.. and eating the Korban lead to the memories of the first time the Israelites brought such a sacrifice, had a meal, and the event that occured with it and thus serves as a moment of remembrance and celebration.

Comment: @user4762 We’re just going in circles here. Can we continue this further in the chat room on the question?